# laravel - no se puedo encontrar el controlador (SQL: select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = migrations)

Tags: laravel-5, test

estoy realizando test driven development en laravel
en laragon. en el test feature
en el test escribi

```
use RefreshDatabase;

public function an_authenticated_user_can_create_statuses()
{
    // $this->assertTrue(true);
    // 1. Given => Teniendo un usuario autenticado
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    $this->actingAs($user);
    // 2. When => Cuando hace un post request a status
    $this->post(route('statuses.store'), ['body' => 'Mi primer status']);
    // 3. Then => Entonces veo un nuevo estado en la base de datos
    $this->asserDatabaseHas('statuses', [
        'body' => 'Mi primer status'
    ]);
}
```

en el archivo phpunit.xml agrege

```
<env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
```

pero en consola me da como resultado

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table' and name = migrations)
```

Comment: el error me daba porque en laragon debo habilitar las extensiones Sqlite en Menú> PHP> Extensiones>pdo_sqlite

Comment: No añadas la respuesta al cuerpo de tu pregunta, para eso está abajo la zona de respuestas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

el error me daba porque en laragon debo habilitar las extensiones Sqlite en Menú> PHP> Extensiones>pdo_sqlite

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser por que no tienes instalado php7.1-sqlite3, revisa si lo tienes instalado y configurado correctamente en php y laravel

si estas en linux:

> sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite3

si estas en windows consulta:

[Instalacion SQLite](http://www.sqlitemanager.org/en/installation/sqlite/installing-sqlite3-on-windows.html)